# How to fix 'invalid resource directory name <folder_name> error in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android

I'm currently working on a project using Xamarin.Android.

I created a 2 files for translate animations of a DialogFragment
    -> Resources\animations\slide_up.xml
    -> Resources\animations\slide_right.xml

I created an style entry for the animations and included them as items pointing the file path above

```
<style name="dialog_animation">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@animations/slide_up</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@animations/slide_right</item>
</style>
```

However, when trying to build, I get the error message: 'Invalid Resource Directory Name: path\to\debug\81\res animations "res animations"'

Could someone help me with a fix for this?

I've tried to clean, and rebuild... 
Also Set Build Action for Resources to None, but still no go...  :'(

Comment: could it work now ?

Comment: Yes, it did work @Leo Zhu...

Answer (score 2):

> Resources\animations\slide_up.xml ->
>   Resources\animations\slide_right.xml

Your file is misnamed ：

the file for animation should be named `anim`,
the directory should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Leo. It worked for me... Sorry for the late reply.